# Building a Repository using ServiceStack.ORMLite

Tags: repository-pattern, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I'm using servicestack and i'm planning to use ormlite for the data access layer.
I've these tables (SQL Server 2005)

```
Table ITEM
ID PK
...

Table SUBITEM1
ID PK FK -> ITEM(ID)
...

Table SUBITEM2
ID PK FK -> ITEM(ID)
...

Table POST
ID PK
...

Table COMMENT
ID PK
...

Table DOWNLOAD
ID PK
...

Table POST_COMMENT
ID PK
POST_ID FK -> POST(ID)
COMMENT_ID FK -> COMMENT(ID)

Table DOWNLOAD_COMMENT
ID PK
DOWNLOAD_ID FK -> DOWNLOAD(ID)
COMMENT_ID FK -> COMMENT(ID)
```

I created a class for each table and mapped them using annotations (autoincrement, references, etc).

I decided to creare a repository for each "entity" (item, post, comment, download).
Each repository contains the basic CRUD logic,

eg. 1 CommentRepository has a Save(Comment comment, Object relationship) that performs db.Insert(comment, relationship) where relationship is PostComment or DownloadComment.

eg. 2 PostRepository has a Save(Post p) that performs the insert into POST.

I'm not sure about this solution because the repository interface is different and I can't do polymorphic queries.

Can you provide any advice to improve my DAL?

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not a fan of forced artificial abstraction so I don't like starting with a repository for every entity as it will just lead to un-necessary code-bloat. I like to start with only 1 repository for all entities encapsulating all data access and refactor naturally out when it gets too big.

I don't know enough of your domain to know what the best RDBMS layout is but I also like to avoid creating un-necessary tables where possible and will look to blob non-aggregate root data, e.g. if SubItem can only applies and is not meaningful outside the context of its parent Item, then I would just blob it saving a couple of tables, e.g:

```
class Item {
   int Id; //PK, AutoIncr
   List<SubItem> SubItem;
}
```

Rather than the separate Many : Many tables, I would just maintain it on the single Comment table, e.g:

```
class Comment {
    int Id; //PK, AutoIncr
    string CommentType; //i.e. Post or Download
    int RefId;
    string Comment;
}
```

So my repository would mimic the data access patterns required for fulfilling the Web Request, something like:

```
class BlogRepository {
    void AddCommentToPost(int postId, Comment comment);
    void AddCommentToDownload(int downloadId, Comment comment);
}
```

Comment: hi mythz, I really appreciate your answer.

Comment: hi mythz, I really appreciate your answer. I can modify the many-to-many relationship between post, download and comment as you suggested but i can't modify the item/subitem hierarchy. SubItem1 and SubItem2 are subclass of Item and I can't use blob data because there are triggers that populate these tables.

Comment: @mythz I really agree with your dislike of artificial abstractions, particularly the 1 to 1 mapping of repository to entity.  Much prefer organic growth